# Extjs 4 actioncolumn issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an `Ext.grid.Panel` with this items:

```
items:[
                   {
                           xtype:'actioncolumn', 
                           width:20,
                           align:'center',
                           items: [
                                   {
                                       icon:'resources/images/icons/table_edit.png',
                                       tooltip: 'Edita Registro',
                                       action:'edit'
                                   },
                           ]
                   },
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Estado</span>', dataIndex:'testado', width:90},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Cliente</span>', dataIndex:'tcliente', width:110, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">N&#176; Expediente</span>', dataIndex:'Expediente', width:100},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Organismo</span>', dataIndex:'torganismo', width:255, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Convocatoria</span>', dataIndex:'F_Convocatoria', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Presentacion</span>', dataIndex:'F_Presentacion', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Aviso</span>', dataIndex:'F_Aviso', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Importe sin IVA</span>', dataIndex:'Total_Licitacion_sIVA', width:105, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Responsable</span>', dataIndex:'tresponsable', width:140, sortable: true},
            ]
```

In my controller I want to hand when user clicks on the button of the `actioncolumn`. I have the following code:

```
this.control({
    'viewGridRECO actioncolumn':{
        click:this.onPulsarEditar
    }
});
```

With the previous code in my controller,the function onPulsarEditar executes when the user clicks everywhere in the cell of the action column,but I want it to execute only when click on the button,not everywhere in the cell of the actioncolumn.

I have tried to put `action:'edit'` property in the button and in the controller:

```
this.control({
    'viewGridRECO actioncolumn button[action=edit]':{
        click:this.onPulsarEditar
    }
});
```

And nothing happends.

Comment: Have you tried solution provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066941/extjs-grid-handling-action-columns-click-event-in-the-controller ?

Comment: I didn´t find this post searching solutions to my issue. It works perfect,thanks a lot.

Comment: Bravo.. You are welcome :)
It would be nice if you post a brief answer to your question and accept it so that future visitors to this post can see an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@Abdul Rehman Yawar Khan` comented to view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066941/extjs-grid-handling-action-columns-click-event-in-the-controller) post, after update my code it is:

In the view,the `column items`:

```
items:[
                   {
                           xtype:'actioncolumn', 
                           width:20,
                           align:'center',
                           items: [
                                   {
                                       icon:'resources/images/icons/table_edit.png',
                                       tooltip: 'Edita Registro',
                                       handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
                                            this.fireEvent('itemClick', view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row, 'edit');
                                       }
                                   }
                           ]
                   },
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Estado</span>', dataIndex:'testado', width:90},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Cliente</span>', dataIndex:'tcliente', width:110, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">N&#176; Expediente</span>', dataIndex:'Expediente', width:100},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Organismo</span>', dataIndex:'torganismo', width:255, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Convocatoria</span>', dataIndex:'F_Convocatoria', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Presentacion</span>', dataIndex:'F_Presentacion', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Aviso</span>', dataIndex:'F_Aviso', width:80, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Importe sin IVA</span>', dataIndex:'Total_Licitacion_sIVA', width:105, sortable: true},
                   {header:'<span style="color:blue;">Responsable</span>', dataIndex:'tresponsable', width:140, sortable: true},
            ]
```

In the controller:

```
this.control({
    'actioncolumn':{
        itemClick:this.onPulsarEditar
});
```

Note that `itemClick` of actioncolumn in controller is write the same way as it is in the view handler event.

And in the controller in the function `onPulsarEdit` you can add all the code you need to execute the function as you want.